# Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

im trying to get max value from my table and want to add it by 1.
here is it my controller :

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT max(id_pelanggan) from pelanggan');
$id_pelanggan = $query + 1;
```

the error i get is

> Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Comment: $query is just a pointer to a result. you have to actually *fetch* the result first. have you even read one tutorial or manual about database interaction in php?

Comment: no, i havent read the manual, but im now reading the manual. i dont read manual because i dont know what to search... thank you....

Comment: Read this then : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: im done reading, but my query is "select max(id_pelanggan) from pelanggan" what to write when inserting the result to the variable ? ive tried "$id_pelanggan->max(id_pelanggan)" but its still error but different.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT max(id_pelanggan) id_pelanggan from pelanggan');
$query = $query->row();
$query = $query->id_pelanggan;
$id_pelanggan = $query + 1;
```

Comment: thank you so much my friend. i do this for learning btw, not for a project. im trying to understand the code right now. it will really help if you explain this. :)

Comment: after executing the $this->db->query(); you need to return the result as an array object using $query->row(); so you can fetch the result by calling the array + the column name of table. $query->id_pelanggan;